# Plex server transfer speeds

Tags: networking, server, ethernet, transfer, plex

I've built a Plex server using some older equipment I had and am using Samba to connect to the server to transfer my media onto it. The transfers are super slow. Could someone tell me if there are things I can do to speed them up or if they are transferring at maximum.

The servers spec is an Asus P5W DH Deluxe (dual gigabit ethernet) and a Q6600.

I am transferring from my iMac connected over wifi and the server is connected with ethernet to the router.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The wifi speed will be delimiting. Change to wired Cat 6a cable between the server and router, ad well as between router and computer. Make also sure you router has gigabit lan ports.

Comment: I would change to ethernet between the iMac and the router but it's just not feasible at the current time. The router is a Netgear N300. Any other solutions?

Comment: How fast is the connection now?

Comment: What is the best way of checking the connection speed between the two?

Comment: Copy a large file and check the status or with iperf program.

Comment: Saying 2 hours for a 3gb file

Comment: The samba should copy this in 15 min. Check your cable to the plex server, whether it has no sharp bends or kinks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35929/discussion-between-rctneil-and-kukulo).